# how to add values in nsmutable array in cellForRowatIndexpath method for each row?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, nsmutablearray

i am trying to add number of lines of each ui table view cell's textview .For this i have made  an nsmutable array in rowatIndexpath and tried adding values in that array .Problem is that only one value is added in array and not all the 10/10 values of uitable view.plz help.

linesAtRowIndexPath was declared as an extension in the same file.

```
linesAtRowIndexPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
int lines = cell.txtViewMessage.contentSize.height / cell.txtViewMessage.font.lineHeight;

int height ;


if(lines > 6 )
{
    height =220;


    [linesAtRowIndexPath addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:height]];
}
   else{


    height = 100;
       [linesAtRowIndexPath addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:height]];

}
```

Comment: Can you show the full implementation of both the delegate methods you are using?

Comment: Have you tried working out the order in which the TVC methods execute? That may help you understand the process of how iOS builds a table view, and where you have opportunity to obtain data. I suspect you will need to build your `NSMutableArray` in one of the TVC lifecycle methods (e.g. `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: Just put break points for all the datasource/delegate methods which you are using in your controller. You will come to know the order in which it gets called. As per your question, `heightForRow` gets called first and then `cellForRow`. So you need to change your logic a bit.

Comment: Seems a bit of an upside down way of trying to achieve height constraints on a cell's label. UITableView's delegate methods execute in a specific order. Height For Row is done ahead of cell for row so trying to get heights calculated in cell for row means you would have to do another load (or reload) of the table with the calculated heights - messy. If you explain more what you are trying to achieve I may be able to help. There are ways of achieving this in code or Auto Layout for a painless way. TableView heights have always been a bit back to front but workable if you know what you're doing.

Comment: i have textview inside my uitable view cell . i want to resize my cell 's height when there are different number of lines in uitextview

Answer (score 0):

A often used pattern to achieve this is to have a class method in the tableViewCell subclass like `+(CGFloat)height`, which returns a value. 
In your case you might have something like `+(CGFloat)heightWithText:` and do your calculation there.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to calculate Number of Line in your textview cell the you can do this by calling this method :

```
-(int)getLine:(UITextView *)txtView{
    int txtLine = txtView.contentSize.height / txtview.font.lineHeight;
    return txtLine;
}
```

Comment: how can i add number of lines in textview of ui table view cell in viewdidload??

Comment: so know what u would like to do ... tell in detail , if you would like to add each line in Array then allocate it in view did load 
and then insert value in it as you are doing so that you will get all values.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate your array in viewWillAppear instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath
May this help you..!!